# Mapbox search bar doesent load location

Tags: leaflet, draw, mapbox, searchbar

I have 2 toolbars in my scrpit one to add markers and another one to search locations but when i had both in the scrpit the location bar stop fiding location can you tell me why ? i am new at leaflet and mapbox

```html
<style>
#geocoder-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#geocoder-container > div {
    min-width:50%;
    margin-left:25%;
}
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<div id='geocoder-container'></div>
<script>
<!-- MAP Feature--> 
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoib2JlY2VuZSIsImEiOiJjaXNicjdja3kwMDE3MnBvMGppMWpubDBqIn0.L4r0u_Em0utvCuFmqbsWQw';
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
      .setView([38.89399, -77.03659], 17);

  var featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
<!-- MAP Feature--> 
<!-- Tolbar eddit --> 
  var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
    edit: {
      featureGroup: featureGroup
    }
  }).addTo(map);

  map.on('draw:created', function(e) {
      featureGroup.addLayer(e.layer);
  });
var geocoder = new mapboxgl.Geocoder({
    container: 'geocoder-container' 
});

map.addControl(geocoder);

 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code snippet isnt including any scripts.